# How to update scripts using byte encoding for file access on MS-Windows to Python3.5?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, encoding

Python 3.3 [deprecated using bytes for filepaths](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#deprecated-python-modules-functions-and-methods) (on MS-Windows only).

Python 3.5 no longer supports bytes for [os.listdir](http://bugs.python.org/issue25911).

---

So my question is, say I have existing code which is using bytes for filepaths on MS-Windows.

How would you convert bytes to string for accessing files in a way that has
*****exactly the same behavior as Python3.4***** ?

---

Note, I'm aware of `sys.getfilesystemencoding`, however this may be set to `ascii`, which will give errors encoding some of some byte strings (something which didn't happen when accessing files with bytes).

Comment: If you copy the 3.4 os.walk code into your program and continue letting Windows do the conversion (using the code page), 3.4 and 3.5 should work the same.

Comment: Right, this is an option, but since bytes for paths is deprecated for all file access on ms-windows, I'd rather update the code not to use deprecated functions at all - while not introducing new bugs.

Comment: 3.5 supports `bytes` paths on POSIX, and should always support them. For Windows, use `str` instead since that calls the native wide-character APIs. Cross-platform code should also use `str`.  To decode `bytes` paths on POSIX, use [`os.fsdecode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsdecode). This smuggles unmapped codes as surrogate pairs using the `surrogateescape` error handler.

Comment: My general advice would be do as eryksun suggests.  My advice-free answer was in response to your bold-face double-starred requirement, which would include reproducing any current bugs ;-).

Comment: @eryksun, according to the docs `os.fsdecode` uses the `strict` error handler on windows (meaning that it will raise an error if it cant decode the byte string)

Comment: @eryksun, I'm not concerned it *displays* correctly or not, as long as the file-paths resolve and file access remains working. However, if `os.fsdecode` can give errors because of strict encoding - then this is a regression from using byte strings directly (aka will introduce bugs from a users perspective).

The file paths come from a text file format thats been around for years, without defining an encoding which files should be written in.

Comment: I took another look at how byte values roundtrip through the ANSI translation layer, and I think you have a valid use case. That's assuming it's reasonable to create nonsense filenames. I was concerned that some of the ANSI tables would use "?" as a replacement character, which would fail to roundtrip. However, what actually happens, for example, is `b'\x81'` is harmlessly decoded as `u"\x81"` if the ANSI codepage is 1252, which doesn't map code 0x81. This roundtrips fine when listing the directory.

Comment: The *nonsense filenames* are often user-names, I dont know details of windows encoding, we just had user reports that they couldn't read/write from their home directories on windows.

Tested `for i in range(1024): os.fsdecode(os.urandom(1024))` and this doesn't throw any encoding errors *(of course its possible it randomly gave perfect encoding :) ... ok, not likely)*.  So now Im wondering if the documentation is wrong by stating its using `strict` error handler.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with a single-byte ANSI codepage such as 1252. However, I overlooked DBCS codepages. With a Japanese system locale (DBCS codepage 932), arbitrary bytes paths *don't rountrip*. Specifically, if a lead byte (i.e. 0x81-0x9F, 0xE0-0xFC) is followed by a trailing byte with a value less than 0x40 (note 0-9 map to 0x30-0x39 in ASCII), it's an error for `os.fsdecode`. In this case, the Windows ANSI API substitutes the default character for Japanese, "・" (U+30FB, Katakana middle dot), which roundtrips as `b'\x81\x45'`.